# Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundle-install, cacerts

I'm trying to install a Ruby project on my Linux system, when I run this command:

```
bundle install --jobs=$(nproc) --retry=5
```

I got this error:

[image]

This is the full output of the above command:

```
Fetching source index from https://enterprise.contribsys.com/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/6): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://enterprise.contribsys.com/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/6): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://enterprise.contribsys.com/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/6): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://enterprise.contribsys.com/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying fetcher due to error (5/6): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://enterprise.contribsys.com/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying fetcher due to error (6/6): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://enterprise.contribsys.com/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://enterprise.contribsys.com/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect
without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

In my Gemfile I tried to switch from https to http but still the same problem.

I have been searching for answers and all I found it is an issue related to openssl and how rvm manage it, also it is a matter of ca-certificates.

So, my question is: is there a way to use bundle install with an specific openssl version?

As an example, if I want to install a different Ruby version I use this command:

```
rvm install 2.7.6 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr --autolibs=disable
```

Any hints how to overcome this error?

Comment: That screenshot is completely unreadable. Can you post it as *plain text*? It helps  with readability and searchability, too.

Comment: What dependency is failing? What `gem` declaration does that correspond with?

Comment: original post edited with the requested info

Comment: Is that an up-to-date version of RVM and/or OpenSSL? It seems like the installation's root certificates have expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I found was to switch to rbenv, after that, all problems solved it.